# Multiple tables in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have 3 tables:

Student

```
   StudentID -PK
   StudentName
```

Test

```
 TestID - PK
 StudentID-FK
 TestName
```

Marks

```
 MarksID -PK
 TestID-FK
 Marks
```

I want to fetch data for a particular student. My query will be

```
var result = db.Student
               .Include("Test")
               .Include("Marks")
               .FirstOrDefault(c => c.StudentID == '123');
```

When I query for only `Student` and `Test` the result is correct. When I include the third table ie `Marks` I get an error:

> `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.InvalidIncludePathError': Unable to find navigation 'Marks' specified in string based include path 'Marks'. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'CoreEventId.InvalidIncludePathError' to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'.'

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Show classes, not abstract tables.

Comment: That's why you should always use the lambda version of `Include`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Marks` is a navigational property of `Test` and *not* `Student`, you need to do a `ThenInclude("Marks")` instead of `Include()` since that is basing itself off of `Student` and not `Test`.